# JavaScript: Object Construct with object parameter

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

I have seen some code with something like the following:

```
var thing=Object(stuff);    //  stuff is an object
```

where `stuff` is an object.

(I have seen this sort of code on Mozilla’s web site in a polyfill for `Object.assign`).

The documentation on Mozilla is not specific about what it means if the parameter is an object.

As far as I can tell, the new object is a reference to the original object. I thought that you would get the same if you simply wrote:

```
var thing=stuff;    //  stuff is an object
```

What is the difference between the two?

**Edit**

Do I need to say it? This is *not* a question about `Object.assign`. It’s a question about using the `Object` constructor.

Comment: If `stuff` is an object, it does not make a difference indeed. The point is that `stuff` is not always an object.

Answer (score 0):

difference between literal and Object() -

> The Object constructor creates an object wrapper for the given value.
>   If the value is null or undefined, it will create and return an empty
>   object, otherwise, it will return an object of a Type that corresponds
>   to the given value. If the value is an object already, it will return
>   the value.
>
> When called in a non-constructor context, Object behaves identically
>   to new Object(). - 
>   [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

If you use Object, you can insert any value  and get new object, but if  you use object as argument of Object -you get link to this object.
if `stuff` is object , `var thing=Object(stuff);`  and  `var thing=stuff;` are equivalent, else if stuf   for example is number :

`var thing=Object(stuff);`  ---object;

`var thing=stuff;` ---number;

Answer (score -1):

The polyfill for `Object.assign` allows us to merge multiple objects at a time.
Your point on creating a new Object is true but there are difference use cases.

Consider we have 3 objects and we want to merge them:

```
const a = { 'key1': 'value1' };
const b = { 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'this will get replaced' };
const c = { 'key3': 'value3' };

// Using Object.assign
const abc = Object.assign(a, b, c);
// abc will have the value {key1: "value1", key2: "value2", key3: "value3"}
```

Comment: if you are using es5 then it will give you syntax error for const. Change them to var for es5. There are no syntex errors.

Comment: Try it now. Sorry about the comma.

Comment: @BrijeshBhakta I don’t think that addresses the question. I know what `Object.assign` does: I was just mentioning that the polyfill was where I saw the code. The question is: What is the purpose of using the `Object` constructor with an object parameter? BTW, I think you might have some problems if your object `a` is a constant; `Object.assign` is supposed to change the target object.

Comment: Yes it is supposed to change the target object but it will not give any error for const as we can still modify the object even if it is a const. Like we are not re-assigning the const variable but just adding other properties to it.

Comment: I didn’t realise that you can use a constant target without error. Thanks.